# Using On Keyup Function For Live

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to this code to execute after an ajax-call (means .live) How should I change the code?

```
var el=document.getElementById('txt_url');
el.onkeyup=function(){
    var str=el.value;
    if(str=='') return;   
    if(str.indexOf('http://')==-1 && str.length >= 7)
    el.value='http://'+str;   
}
```

Comment: You want this code to execute after an AJAX call? If so you will need to show us the code you are using to make the call, not the code you want to run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To live-bind a handler to an element use the jQuery [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method. (As of jquery 1.7)

```
$("body").on("keyup","#txt_url",function(){
   // your code
});
```

It replaces the deprecated [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) handler.

Also, if you use jQuery, I'd suggest you to use it consistently - also for element-selection and handler-binding.

Alternatively you could bind the handler in the success function but I prefer to do the eventbinding in a more consistent way.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the success handler:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'ajax/test.html',
  success: function(data) {
    var el=document.getElementById('txt_url');
    el.onkeyup=function(){
        var str=el.value;
        if(str=='') return;   
        if(str.indexOf('http://')==-1 && str.length >= 7)
        el.value='http://'+str;   
    }
  }
});
```

[jQuery Ajax Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)